# Why I receive ImportError: cannot import name 'fore' from 'colorama'?

Tags: python, colorama

I can execute colorama module and I receive an error.
My code

```
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import fore, back, style
what = input( print.red + "What kind of operation? (+, -, /, *): ")
a = float( input("Input first number?: ") )
b = float( input("Input second number: ") )
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Final: " + str(c))
if what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("Final: " + str(c))
if what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print("Final: " + str(c))
if what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print("Final: " + str(c))
else:
    print("Please check operation")
```

And error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/projects.py/calclulator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from colorama import fore, back, style
ImportError: cannot import name 'fore' from 'colorama' (D:\projects.py\venv\lib\site-packages\colorama\__init__.py)
```

Im using PyCharm as IDK
When I running it without colorama i dont has any errors
Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you should be importing are `Fore`, `Back`, and `Style`. Watch out for those capital letters!